# Google Cloud Messaging on a non-PlayStore App

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, google-cloud-messaging, device-owner

Working on a device-owner application (installed at provision time with NFC), so far [I did not find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28777354/1720332) any way to provision devices directly with a PlayStore-based-App, that is why I keep using a private distribution mode for my apk, directly downloaded from a private server...

In this context here is my question: is there a way to use GCM with an App that isn't distributed on the Google Play Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Developers will be able to sign-up for GCM for both Play and non-Play apps. However, GCM stats will be available for only published Google Play apps.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en)** So yes, I believe you can use GCM with a non-Play Store app.

Comment: Thanks for this detail that I missed ! However, only an API Key is not enough, it needs to be paired with an App to get a sender ID Key... And I did not find a way to get this sender ID by another way than registering an app... strange...