# Is it possible to upgrade a device owner app through Google Play?

Tags: android, device-owner

I've created a device owner app, which I install through a QR code when I factory reset my devices. Everything's fine until here.

Now I have a new version of the same device owner app, and I want to update the devices which have the previous version to this new version.

Is it possible to achieve this using Google Play?

I don't want to use custom methods like uploading the APK somewhere and downloading it with some Java code, because I want to centralize the releases in Google Play.

So far I have uploaded the new version (version code is 5, old one is 2) of the app to Google Play and tried to upgrade from there, but it does not work: in Google Play I just see the app as installed, and the "Disable" and "Open" button, but not the button to upgrade it.

Any thoughts? I've found some posts like the ones below, but they're 5 years old, maybe something has changed and this is not longer possible.

- [Install updates for a Device-Owner App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273925/install-updates-for-a-device-owner-app)
- [Install a GooglePlay located App from NFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777354/install-a-googleplay-located-app-from-nfc)

I haven't been able to find any specific information on updates with device owner apps. The documentation is extensive about how to create and install a device owner app, but not on how to upgrade it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't install it from play store , I THINK you can't update Device-Owner apps which were not installed from play store , except for the way you mentioned.

Comment: But a device owner app cannot be installed from PlayStore, as far as I know. Is there anyway to install from GooglePlay?